# How can I make it so that my rails app synchronizes the view to every single user that goes on it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, background-process

I am creating a rails app where users can vote on an item every 15 seconds. I want the same item to show up for every user on this website. Basically, I want each session to be synchronized in the content shown. There are two ways that I believe this can be done, but I am not totally sure about the implementation of them. One way is to define a global variable for such an item every 15 seconds. This global variable needs to be the same across all sessions on this website. Another way is to have some background process or main thread running in the back that chooses this item every 15 seconds, and each session gets the current item from this background process. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: will you show us what you have done so far? try to follow one of the path you have proposed and ask for help if you get stuck with the code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless you know what you're doing and have absolutely no other alternative ... **Stay away from global variables**.

If the thing your users are voting on is a record in a database, you already have a shared object available to all sessions at the same time. What is important here is that you ensure all of your sessions refresh their copy of that object at least every 15 seconds.

The easiest solution here would be to have a little Javascript in your page using a timeout loop to fetch a new copy of the data and update your view.